# Can I use a 1:1 mixture of isopentyl alcohol and water as mobile phase to carry out paper chromatography of a mixture of red and blue ink?

Tags: chromatography

> Can I use a 1:1 mixture of isopentyl alcohol and water as mobile phase to carry out paper chromatography of a mixture of red and blue ink?

We generally use ethanol water mixture as mobile phase for separating mixture of blue and red ink using paper chromatography. Can I expect better results with isopentyl alcohol and water mixture?

[image: chromatography of two-component ink]

Comment: Who said you _can_ mix them 1:1?

Comment: Isoamyl alcohol is only sparingly soluble in water: $28\ \mathrm{gL^{-1}}$ (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

The principle of chromatography is that you can always *try* (as per the question in the title). This can be beneficial: in my PhD thesis I had two diastereomers that were hard to separate on TLC using hexanes and ethyl acetate, but a hexanes/toluene mixture worked wonders.

However, in your case you should not expect better results. For one, as the commentators have pointed out the two liquids are not sufficiently soluble in each other. For two, your separation is already pretty good and it seems unlikely that it can be improved even more.